# Using xpath to get multiple selective values from within a single DIV class

Tags: python, xml, xpath, screen-scraping

I'm scraping a website with Python using Xpath and wish to return multiple elements within a

```
div class
```

I have narrowed down the information in question using

```
//*[@class='category-product js-productitem']
```

And this selection is on Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/0A6LQ9DC

I'd like to be able to extract multiple bits of info from this one selection. For example, 'data-productid', 'data-price', 'data-specialprice' etc

I'd like to understand how to express the Xpath equivalent to the SQL

```
SELECT data-productid, data-price, data-specialprice FROM category-product js-productitem
```

Whilst learning about Xpath, absolute/relative paths have confused me somewhat. I am assuming if I reference a *unique combination* of tags/names in this way (and not relative paths) I can be sure to only get the info I am expecting, having checked this via Google Chromes 'inspect' function.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "root path" and the @ attribute symbol to get (get()) what you need. With scrapy shell :

```
response.xpath('//*[@class='category-product js-productitem']/@data-productid').get()
response.xpath('//*[@class='category-product js-productitem']/@data-price').get()
response.xpath('//*[@class='category-product js-productitem']/@data-specialprice').get()
```